# Obtener dias de una semana en un año, php

Tags: php

Hola chicos gracias por su ayuda, deseo saber como puedo obtener las fechas de una semana en un año especifico, actualmente pude encontrar como hacerlo pero para el año actual, así:

```
$week = 2;
    for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++)
    {
        echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('01/01 +' . ($week - 1) . ' weeks first day +' . $i . ' day')) . '<br />';
    }
```

pero si quisiera decir que quiero obtener los dias de la semana 2 del año 2010, como sería?.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se si he entendido muy bien lo que quieres lograr pero creo que esto te puede ayudar, estas son las lineas que uso yo para obtener el dia de la semana de una fecha.

```
$diaSemana = date("N", strtotime($_POST["fecha"]));
$ano = date("Y", strtotime($_POST["fecha"]));
$mes = date("m", strtotime($_POST["fecha"]));
$dia = date("d", strtotime($_POST["fecha"]));
```

Lo tengo puesto con el post porque lo he cogido directamente de mi código. Pero el formato de la fecha lo defino con jQuery.datapicker de esta manera:

```
 <input id="fecha" name="fecha" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fecha'])){echo $_POST['fecha'];}else{echo date('Y/m/d');} ?>">    

<script>

$(function() {
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['eu']);
    $( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'}); 
});

</script>
```

Asi es como lo hago yo espero que por lo menos te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Algo así:

```
$week = 2;
$year = 2010;
for($day=0; $day<7; $day++)
{
    echo date('y/m/d', strtotime($year."W".$week.$day))."\n";
}
```

La variable $year serviría para determinar el año del que estás buscando la semana, que es lo que estabas solicitando, deberías darle el valor necesario antes de entrar al ciclo for, y ésto te devolvería los días de la semana $week para el año $year

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para mejorar el formato de la misma, pero es recomendable que agregues una explicación de este código. Saludos